# update sql query stops updating excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a classic ASP web application that updates a table in a Excel spreadsheet.

I am using the following to connect to the Excel file

```
Set rows = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("data.xlsx") & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=" &  Chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes" & Chr(34) & ";"
```

That is a sample query that I am executing

```
query = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [STATUS] = 'unclaimed', [CLAIMER] = '' ,[SDATE] = '" 
& DATE & "' WHERE [JUR] = '" & in_jur & "' AND [WC] = " & in_wc 
objConnection.Execute query,numRows,adExecuteNoRecords
```

The above query gets executed in the process.asp page when the user clicks on a button that calls a javascript function that sends the value of in_jur and in_wc like this

```
function sendForProcessing() {
    somejur = //use the document.getElementByID to get selected jur
    somewc = //use the document.getElementByID to get selected wc
    window.location = process.asp?in_jur=somejur&in_wc=somewc
}
```

The application updates the sheet correctly for some time (i counted the number of times it works. 1st test: 10 times 2nd test: 16 times it just varies) and then it stops working.
I do not get error message in the objConnection.Execute.

When i print out the numRows it prints 1.

Is there a better way to update the row in Excel?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Are you opening up the Excel file on the server to check, or something else?  Have you tried appending a random querystring parameter to the URL to prevent caching of responses?  As an aside, it's not good practice to use a GET request to perform upddate/delete in a web application.  You should at least use POST instead.

Comment: I am checking the file in the server to check after I notice that the update is not working.

Comment: Before you run the update, run a select using the same `where` clause - does it always find at least one matching record?